# Xcode exported mac app showing error "powerpc applications are no longer supported"

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks, cocoapods

I've made simple Mac app in Xcode 5, Archived and Exported it as application without signing.
App runs properly on my Mac that it was build on but don't on any other. When I try to open it on different Mac error message "powerpc applications are no longer supported" appears.

Comment: post your build settings please.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Here are the settings: http://pastebin.com/jm488yBz

Comment: 1. has this project been updated to the latest xcode settings?
2. is this "other mac" a PPC mac?!?

Comment: It's MacBook Pro from second half of 2010.
I tried with Xcode 5 and new Xcode 6 it's the same error in both cases.

Comment: it has nothing to do with version of Xcode I'm asking about if the  **project settings** have been upgraded to xcode 5+. was this a project that was originally made in xcode 4?

Comment: project was started in xcode 5

Comment: Hi, @siemian. Did you find the problem? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @siemian See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Before send it to another Mac, put it in a zip folder to protect the exported file when downloading.